# Writing .R file from R console without using R or any editor using R commands

Tags: r, console, sink

I want to write out a `.R` file or create an `R script` from `R console`, like we create `.txt` files. But usually when we write out `.txt` files, they contain some `output` and not `commands` to it. So I want to write `R script` from `console` and `save` it by using R commands.

I am not sure if R has `write.R` something like this. I tried using `sink()` command, but again it `outputs the output and not commands`.

```
 sink("Rscriptfrom_Console.R")
 sapply(iris,class)
 sink()
```

Creating an `R script file (.R) from R console using R commands`.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You could create a file and then edit it from R console by doing: `file.create('foo.R') file.edit('foo.R')`.

Comment: I just tried using `writeLines()` and `file()`, it appears it is working. Let me check for by adding more commands and sourcing it.

Comment: Here is a small eg. using `writelines: fileConn<-file("foo.R");writeLines(paste("sapply(","iris,","class)"), fileConn);close(fileConn);source('foo.R')`

Comment: I guess it should be `file.edit` and not `edit`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Do post if you have better answer. 
Using here `file()` and `writeLines()` function and `source()` to check if the written `.R` file is working.

```
  fc <- file("out.R")

  writeLines(c("print(head(iris))",
  "print(summary(iris))"),
  fc)

  close(fc)

  source("out.R")
  #   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  # 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
  # 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
  # 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

  #   Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
  #  Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
  #  1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300  
  #  Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300  
  #  Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
  #  3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
  #  Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500  

  #        Species  
  #  setosa    :50  
  #  versicolor:50  
  #  virginica :50
```

Comment: I recommend that you don’t use `file`…`close` here: using the filename directly (see my answer) is much simpler. Using `close` and similar functions is generally error-prone: if there’s an error thrown before the `close` call, then execution stops and `close` is never called. To mitigate this, you should *always* use [`on.exit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/on.exit.html) in such a scenario. So in your case, remove `close(fc)` and instead put `on.exit(close(fc))` directly behind your call to `file`.

Comment: Thanks for providing information about this. Give me some time to check on `on.exit` and to implement your example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misunderstand what `sink` does: it captures the *output* and writes it to a file. It doesn’t capture unevaluated R expressions, which is what you want to do.

To capture an unevaluated R expression, you need to wrap it inside [`quote`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html), or use a similar mechanism. To use your example:

```
quoted_expr = quote(sapply(iris, class))
```

Now `quoted_expr` contains the R expression. Next, you need to convert it into a string representation of the R code:

```
code_representation = deparse(quoted_expr, backtick = TRUE)
```

The `backtick = TRUE` isn’t strictly necessary here but it’s good practice to always use it because there are certain cases where it’s necessary.

Finally, we can write this code representation to a file:

```
writeLines(code_representation, 'code.r')
```

Now, the above example wrote a fixed R expression into a file. We might as well have used a character string throughout. But using a quoted expression instead of the character string gives us the ability to change the code on the fly, without having to muck around with the string (error-prone and inefficient). For instance, we could let the user decide which data.table to work on:

```
dataset_name = 'mtcars' # Modify to your heart’s content
quoted_expr = substitute(sapply(dataset, class),
                         list(dataset = as.name(dataset_name)))

# `quoted_expr` is now:
sapply(mtcars, class)
```

… etc.